# How to sync a folder between multiple PC and Android devices using a local network such as Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, sync, android

Basically What I'm looking for is a software/ program / anything that can help me achieve the following objective :

I have a folder that is full of PDFs and I have multiple devices ( Android and Windows devices ) where I use these files but I have to copy a file to all of my devices whenever I make an edit to a file on one of my devices. So I want to synchronise these devices but without using internet as all of my devices that I use are usually at my home and I don't need to access my files when I am outside. Therefore I don't prefer cloud services like Dropbox or OneDrive.

So is there anyway to sync a folder on multiple devices ( cross platform ) using a local network such as the Wi-Fi Hotspot ( or maybe Bluetooth ) of my mobile devices, so that whenever I connect my devices to a single Hotspot then all the edits that I made in anyone of the devices get synchronised across all of my devices without consuming my Internet data pack ?

Comment: You can create a network share of the folder where those files reside.

Comment: Other than storing the files at a network share and accessing them as needed, you always will end up with a cloud storage solution. If mobile devices were not in the list, there would have been other solutions, but on android, there isn't an easy sync with network folder solution, because the "mobile" character of these devices will always assume internet sync, not local sync.

Comment: I use Dropbox for this task

Comment: @ChanganAuto How to do that ?

Comment: How to do depends on the OS and OS version of the computer hosting the files and what is supported by all the "clients". Assuming Windows 10 as the "file server" the typical Windows network sharing (with write permissions) should do it for all other PCs even if those are running different OSes. For the mobile clients the situation is pretty much how @LPChip already commented. It's easy to access the file hosted in Windows in the same network, most native/default file managers can have the share saved and easily accessible but won't be syncing in strict sense.

Comment: Please note that with desktop or laptop PC you'll be opening and saving the files directly in the remote share but in Android you'll have to copy/download, edit and then copy it back to and overwrite the original file in the Windows network share.